# Dynamically adding buttons and setting Listeners

Tags: android

I am having trouble with dynamically adding buttons and the setting the onClickListener. This is what I have at the moment:

```
        List<Button> bList = new ArrayList<Button>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            q = i;
            bList.add(new Button(this.activity));
            bList.get(i).setText(Integer.toString(q));
            bList.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    statsButton.setText(Integer.toString(q));
                }
            });
            upgradeLayout.addView(bList.get(i));
        }
```

It is working fine except that the listeners are not working. When I click on the button nothing happens, but the buttons are created just fine.

Comment: That looks about right... have you tried putting a breakpoint in your onClick handler?

Comment: No I havent I will try that

Comment: If you have answered your question, please answer your question and close this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1. **activity_main.xml**

   ```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dynamically adding buttons and setting Listeners" />

     <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
   ```

2.**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addbtnDynamically();
 }


   //Method to generate button dynamically
   private void addbtnDynamically(){
    try{
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn_layout);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++ ){
                Button button = new Button(this);
                button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                button.setText("Button " + (j + 1 + (i * 3)));
                button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                button.setId(j + 1 + (i * 3));
                button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
                row.addView(button);
            }

            layout.addView(row);
        }
    }catch(Exception b){b.printStackTrace();}
}

//Method for click event
private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case 1:
                showToast("Button 1 clicked!");
                break;
            case 2:
                showToast("Button 2 clicked!");
                break;
            case 3:
                showToast("Button 3 clicked!");
                break;
            case 4:
                showToast("Button 4 clicked!");
                break;
    //       .......
        }
     }
    };

     //Method to message
     private void showToast(String content){
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+content,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
 }
```

3.**Result**

you should get output like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this,

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.addbuttondynamic.AddButtonDynamic" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Main.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddButtonDynamic extends Activity {

    LinearLayout upgradeLayout;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_button_dynamic);
        
        upgradeLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         
         for(int k=0; k<3; k++)
         {
             LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
             ll.setId(k+1);
             ll.setLayoutParams(params);
             for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                    Button btn = new Button(this);
                    btn.setId(i+1);
                    btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));
                    btn.setLayoutParams(lprams);
                    final int index = i;
                    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Log.i("TAG", "The index is" + index);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click "+index, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    ll.addView(btn);
                }
             upgradeLayout.addView(ll);
         }

        
    }
}
```